# Running out of Memory when trying to find and replace in a CSV

Tags: python

When trying to Find and Replace on a 12MB CSV, I am running out of memory.

This code checks against a list of 5000 names for names in a CSV file and replaces them with the word 'REDACTED'

I've tried putting this onto an AWS XL instance and still ran out of memory.

```
import csv

input_file = csv.DictReader(open("names.csv"))
newword = 'REDACTED'

with open('new.txt', 'w') as outfile, open('test.txt') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        for oldword, newword in input_file:
            line = line.replace(oldword, newword)
            print('Replaced')
        outfile.write(line)
```

I expect it to output the `new.txt` with the replacements intact. I currently getting `MemoryError`.

Comment: At which line you are getting the OOM? Another thing, how declared `newword` will work if you reassigning it within the loop.

Comment: What's in each row of `names.csv`?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems with your code before we can even check whats causing the MemoryError problem.

`for oldword, newword in input_file:` overrides `newword = 'REDACTED'`

Then, as far as i know, you cannot iterate over DictReader multiple times

```
input_file = csv.DictReader(open("names.csv"))
for line in infile:
    for oldword, newword in input_file:
```

And at last, i assume "names.csv" contains all possible names, why read it with a DictReader. What is the structure of the names file, and if it is a csv-file, shouldn't you only take the values of one column and not the whole line.